# Custom currency system multiplication

Tags: java, multiplication, modulo

I am still learning so go easy on me.

I have following currency system:

3 different coins, lets call them Rhodonite (Red colour), Daranen (gold colour) and Delis (gray colour).
100 Delis equal 1 Daranen, 100 Daranen equal 1 Rhodonite. No limit with Rhodonites.

So I am trying to multiply that currency by a double factor. Heres my function:

```
    public static Price multiply(Price price, double factor) {
       int de = (int)Math.round(price.getDelis() * factor);
       int da = (int)Math.round(price.getDaranen() * factor);
       int r = (int)Math.round(price.getRhodoniten() * factor);
       if ((de / 100) >= 1) {
           de = de % 100;
           da += de / 100;
       }
       if ((da / 100) >= 1) {
           da = da % 100;
           r += da / 100;
       }
       return new Price(r, da, de);
    }
```

So when I am multiplying, if the multiplied delis are greater than 100, it should get added to the daranen, same counts for the daranen and the rhodonites.

Here's an example, multiplied with the factor 2:
Top one is before multiplication, bottom one is multiplied.

[image: Example]

As you can see, the multiplication itself works, but not the addition of the remainder to the next higher coin type. I'm happy for any help, still really new to java.

Comment: [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great tips about debugging that will help you find these kinds of errors in your own code.

Comment: Instead of editing the title, please click the checkmark next to one of the answers below to accept the one that helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest keeping only the Delis and converting them to the other currencies as the other answers suggested. However, to answer your question, as to what you did wrong:

You simply have to flip the lines where you do the modulo operation and where you do the division.

e.g.

```java
de = de % 100;
da += de / 100;
```

should be

```java
da += de / 100;
de = de % 100;
```

Here is the correct code:

```java
public static Price multiply(Price price, double factor) {
    int de = (int) Math.round(price.getDelis() * factor);
    int da = (int) Math.round(price.getDaranen() * factor);
    int r = (int) Math.round(price.getRhodoniten() * factor);
    if ((de / 100) >= 1) {
        da += de / 100;
        de = de % 100;
    }
    if ((da / 100) >= 1) {
        r += da / 100;
        da = da % 100;
    }
    return new Price(r, da, de);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. Thanks for your help, that solved it for me. I guess it makes total sense now, I was quite tired yesterday.

Comment: @arvenyon Instead of this comment, you should accept the answer. This helps AgentM, but also anybody who finds your question.

Comment: @NomadMaker thanks for the info. Marked it as answer.

Answer (score 7):

You should keep track of the actual value of your Delis only, let's say on the screenshot you have 36053 Delis, then you can just do simple operations and whenever you display your value you can format it "text wise".

Note: if you can have values higher than 2147483647 you should go for long instead of int

Comment: Yes, this is even better than my answer. Only convert when displaying the monetary value. Otherwise all calculations are in the smallest denomination.

Answer (score 0):

If I were solving this problem, I would convert the entire price to the smallest coin, then double that, the convert that to the value in all 3 coins.

With that said, the problem with your code is the order of operations:

```
de = de % 100;
da += de / 100;
```

You effectively throw away the "carry" before you add it to the next highest denomination. You need to do this the other way around:

```
da += de / 100; // carry first
de = de % 100;  // then reduce
```

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. Thanks for your help, that solved it for me. I guess it makes total sense now, I was quite tired yesterday.

Comment: @arvenyon We've all been there. I suggest you spend a few minutes reading [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. When you learn these techniques and make them a habit, they can pull you through those times when you aren't at the top of your game.